# xcode - ios - How to most effectively reuse view controllers?

Tags: ios

I have created  a UIViewController with a lot of text fields and text views that is a form for users to fill out user information.

The problem I am having, is for example: The `UIViewController` has 6 different components.

- Username
- Email
- Password
- Confirm Password
- Location
- A Paragraph

A lot of work has gone into creating it because each of the different text inputs, their font, text color, size have been individually set. I want to reuse this view, but modify / override a small amount of the class.

Copying and pasting the class and then changing it doesn't seem practical.

**Is there a way where I can some how set up the class so I can sub class it, then override one of the UITextFields or other objects and methods. So then I can easily distribute this class throughout my project, and simply modify individual text fields or methods?**

Comment: That's a pretty broad subject with several options, including a single class with properties to activate/deactivate/change some of the behaviours, subclassing, delegate or block patterns, custom views, and probably a few more...

Comment: U can create subclass of the UI for each of them then combine with extension/delegate to replace/add extra customization and function to them

Comment: jcaron could you please give an example of including a single class with properties and subclassing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a .xib file with `UIView` which contains all those above options.
2. Create a Objective-C class with subclass of `UIView` and map this class to above .xib file.
3. Generate `IBouteLets` for all UI elements and made those `IBoutlet`s scope to global (i.e declare them in your .h file)
4. Add all delegate methods for `UITextView`/`UITextField`, etc... in this class
5. From any view controller, when you want to add this view to controller's view

   ```
   NSArray * array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
   CustomView * v = (CustomView *) [array objectAtIndex:0];
   ```

Here you have a reference for CustomView class. Its a reusable class wherever you want.

Comment: How would I edit individual objects such as a UITextView ?

Comment: From your .xib file map delegate references of the textfield / textview, etc.. objects to the CustomView class.  That class should implement all the delegate methods. Also define some global functions in CustomView class to access the content of objects ( such as text in textfield, text in textview,etc... ) from controllers class